# Encapsulating business decisions - How to return them

Tags: c#, business-logic

Let's assume we have the following requirement:

- The user enters some data
- The software decides if the user can attach the data to an existing customer or if he needs to create a new one
- Then, the user is presented either a list of customers or a "new customer" page.

My goal is, I don't want to spill business logic (=decision what to do) in the ViewModels of the user interface.

Consider the following peace of example code taken from an imaginary view model:

```
void Main()
{
    var businessLogic = new BusinessLogic();
    var request = new RequestData();

    switch (businessLogic.DecideWhatToDo(request))
    {
        case SelectCustomer select:
            Console.WriteLine("You should select one of the existing customers");
            break;

        case CreateNewCustomer createNew:
            Console.WriteLine("You should create a new customer first");
            break;

        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();  
    }
}
```

This is my first thought on how I would return the decisions made by the business logic.

The decision logic is very important to me, so I definately want to have it in a separate class and unit test it with many different test cases.

But somehow I'm not sure about the switch case. Are there better patterns for this kind of problem?

Comment: This is a very broad question, and there is no single correct answer. There are some common patterns that a lot of people follow, because they work well in most cases - have a look at [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) and [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: Actually we're using MVVM. But I'd like to focus on the switch case.
Is it ok how it's used? Is it okay, that a function returns different types for different decisions?
Or are there better patterns?

Comment: I see. A switch block that requires a different type for each case would probably be better served through polymorphism. Create an `IResult` interface (or whatever you want to call it), with an `Execute()` method. The business layer then returns an `IResult`, and the view model doesn't have to know what it is, it can simply call `Execute()`.